# Typedef array confusion

Tags: c++, arrays, typedef

So i'm supposed to make a programm that stores different licence plates in an array using the typedef command. My friend passed me his code but i didn't actually get his explaination. This is his code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef char string[8]

...functions functions...

int main(){
   string license_plate[100]

...
```

I'm kinda confused about what just happened here. I know what typedef is about but never actually seen it in an array. From what i understood

```
typedef char string[8]
```

means that whenever i write `string[8]` the compiler makes it become `char` instead.

But that didn't make sense to me, why would i type [8] aswell? So i thought this was an error he left and removed the [8], and it compiled without errors.

So i wanted to ask, is it true to say that with my correction `string license_plate[100]` becomes nothing more than `char license_plate[100]`to the compiler's eyes? If so why would i mess myself up by using all of this when i could just type `char license_plate[100]`?

Comment: Either don't do `using namespace std;` (what I recommend) or don't name your type `string`. Remember there is a standard string class `std::string`.

Comment: You should formulate the question this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice? to have more chance of getting an answer. Otherwise, `typedef`is used to give alternative names to an existing type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> typedef char string[8]
> ```

This line of code is a terrible idea. It tells the compiler to treat the name `string` as equivalent to `char[8]`.

The most terrible thing about it is the fact that you are hopelessly confusing yourself, future readers of your code and the compiler itself because there already is the standard `std::string` class.

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef char string[8]; // terrible idea

    // ...

    string x("abc");
    std::cout << x.size() << '\n'; // error
    std::cout << (x + "def") << '\n'; // error
    std::getline(std::cin, x); // error
}
```

This confusion is made even more terrible by the fact that you have used `using namespace std;`. Do not use it. Do yourself a favour and just prepend everything with `std::`.

Another terrible aspect about your `typedef` is that there is hardly an imaginable reason for why you would want to treat a series of eight `char`-sized numbers as something which the source code calls `string`.

If at least it was called something like `char_arr8`; in that case, the `typedef` name would (perhaps) make the code more readable instead of causing confusion.

> ```
> int main(){
>    string license_plate[100]
> ```

This piece of code suggests what you *really* want to do. You want a container of strings and call the container "license_plates". That's fine. Just use `std::vector` and `std::string` to express it in C++.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> license_plates;
    // ...
}
```

If you are absolutely sure that the container will always hold exactly 100 elements, *then* you can use an array:

```
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string license_plates[100];
    // ...
}
```

Or `std::array`:

```
#include <string>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<std::string, 100> license_plates;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You define a type-alias for `char[8]`. So when you do e.g.

```
string license_place[100];
```

it is equivalent to

```
char license_place[100][8];
```